# "Тебе обойму" — слова из песни

Tags: общие-вопросы

В фильме "Бумбараш" есть песня "Марш четвёртой роты". Там есть фраза "Я приду и тебе **обойму**".

Как понимаю "обойму" - это "обниму", а почему теб**е**, а не теб**я**?

Answer (score 2):

Обойму = обниму.
Тебе вместо тебя - стилизация под южнорусский или суржик (русско-украинский).

Answer (score 0):

Это у них простолюдный диалект такой, обратите внимание, что в начале они поют "пратиф тибе вись бедный клас паднялси".
В клипе видно, что наложенный звук не совпадает с тем, что поёт актёр, и скорее всего, это должно было звучать "тибе абайму".
Это как в британском английском "can't buy me love". :-)

Comment: «...должно было звучать "тибе абайму"» А как на самом деле звучит? И почему это именно британский английский?

Comment: Это скорее как "через рваные штаны просвечивало его пролетарское происхождение".

Comment: Это стилизация под "простолюдный диалект", специально созданная для этого фильма и актёра. Она уникальна, больше эти выражения не встречаются нигде.